# vue-material md-tooltip causing infinite render loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-material

If I have the following markup:

```
<template v-if="item.countries">
<span v-for="c in item.countries" :key="c">
  <img class="md-layout-item country-flag" :src="`/static/countries/${c}.svg`" :alt="c"/>
</span>
</template>
```

It works just fine. But if I change it to this:

```
<template v-if="item.countries">
<span v-for="c in item.countries" :key="c">
  <img class="md-layout-item country-flag" :src="`/static/countries/${c}.svg`" :alt="c"/>
  <md-tooltip>hi</md-tooltip>
</span>
</template>
```

(Notice the `md-tooltip` tag). .. it ends up in an infinite render loop, indicated by the following javascript error:

> [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render
>   function. found in ..

This error gets logged around every second or so and causes my CPU to melt. Why does this happen? I never had this problem before and I don't see why it happens and how to solve it.

**Edit 1**: I opened a [Github issue](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/issues/1529) for this

**Edit 2**: This is the full stacktrace:

> vue.esm.js?efeb:578 [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop
>   in a component render function.
>
> found in
>
> --->  at src\components\ArtistReleasesList\ArtistReleasesList.vue
>           at src\components\SubContentHub\SubContentHub.vue
>             at src\components\ArtistDetailsPage\ArtistDetailsPage.vue
>               at src/components/MdContent/MdContent.vue
>                 at src/components/MdApp/MdAppContent.vue
>                   at src/components/MdApp/MdAppInternalDrawer.vue
>                     at src\components\AuthenticatedPage\AuthenticatedPage.vue
>                       at src\components\App\App.vue

**Edit 3**: I published a minimalistic project on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/lr3q0qyyo7). **BEWARE**! This WILL exhaust your CPU and might leave your browser unresponsible. If you cannot close your browser tabs anymore, you can just kill the browser process which consumes the most CPU power and memory to end it.

Comment: Whats does the stack trace show? Console should normally show this.

Comment: @webnoob that's already in the question. it only shows the `[Vue warn] ..` and a stacktrace to the file containing the code snipped from above. .. i pinned it down to this snipped with trial and error, .. the error message/infinite loading comes and goes with the `md-tooltip` tag

Comment: You don't get anything else? When I get a infinite loops, I also get to drill down into the methods being called. I accept this might be coming from`md-tooltip` but that should still show a call stack of the methods within that component. I don't think you're going to get much help on this unless you can provide a minimal example.

Comment: @webnoob I appended the full stacktrace, but this is probably not very useful since you do not know what my other components look like.  .. I'll try to make a minimal example, but I'm pretty much certain that this will not be reproducible, since I've never had problems with `md-tooltip` before. But I'll see what I can do.. Also, it doesn't show which methods are being called, just the component hirarchy

Comment: You're right, the stack trace doesn't help in this instance. I find it odd there's no method calls. I think the only way we'll be able to help in this instance is with an example.
The other alternative you have is to copy the `md-tooltip` component from the source and see if it happens with that, if it does, narrow it down (which should be easier seeing as you have the source...)

Comment: @webnoob there you go. I added an example on codesanbox